# How to run ng command when Angular is installed locally?

Tags: node.js, angular, bash, angular-cli, node-modules

I have installed Angular locally in my project using npm. However, when I try to run the `ng` command, it says that the command is not found. I have tried installing Angular globally and it works fine, but I want to use the local installation.

I know I have to export the path of the Angular CLI, but I don’t know how to identify the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run it using package manager `npm/yarn ng`

Answer (score 0):

When you say "installed Angular locally", are you referring to the Angular CLI?

I have a project that is current Angular v14 and has the Angular CLI installed locally. If I open the project in VSCode and use the VS Code command prompt, it uses the local version of the Angular CLI.

So `ng v` displays Angular v14 (even though I have the v16 version of the Angular CLI installed globally).

Are you able to run the local Angular CLI commands from within VS Code for the project?

Comment: yes... currently I have started doing my projects in github codesapaces.

There I am trying to install angular cli locally not using the -g argument.

But after my installation... it just says that ng is not recognized by bash. 

and this is because of the bash command not saved in my bash profile path.

Comment: I am to run my project but it uses the global cli.

Comment: I am a big fan of your content. I really appreciate your contribution to the angular community.

Comment: Does anything here help regarding the path: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27184

Answer (score 0):

Use `npx ng serve` or `npm start` if your `package.json` contains a `"start": "ng serve"` entry under `"scripts"` section!

Also, the global installation realises there's a "local" version and it automatically switches to using that one